# Moment.js bug while adding 1 week at last week of year

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am trying to add one week whatever user has selected week and year and i need output in 'week year' format.

I tried to use momentjs. check below example, instead of giving '1 2016' its giving '1 2015'.

```js
var test = moment('52 2015','w YYYY').add(1,'w').format('w YYYY');
$('body').html(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

52th week of 2015 starts on 2015-12-20; one week later, it is 2015-12-27. No bug in Moment.js - not all years have 52 weeks. (Note that 1st week of 2015 starts in 2014.)

EDIT: This is a bit confusingly stated, and indeed Moment.js is being confusing itself:

```
moment('1 2015','w YYYY').format('w YYYY')
// => 1 2014
```

In the parsing, `YYYY` refers to the year where you count weeks; accidentally, the date for the start of that week lies in the previous year. In formatting, `YYYY` refers to the year the date is in. I guess one could call that a bug; it is certainly unexpected.

EDIT2: How to do it? You do it yourself. There is something strange if month is not January and week is 1st week of the year; so increment the year.

```js
function weekAndYear(date) {
  var week = date.week();
  var year = date.year();
  if (date.month() && week == 1) {
    year++;
  }
  return '' + week + ' ' + year;
}
document.body.textContent = weekAndYear(moment('52 2015','w YYYY').add(1,'w'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.10.6/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Also be aware that `week()` (and `w` specifier) are locale-dependent, and will give you different results in different places.

Comment: Then how to get next epi week ? so if user select '52 2015' then how to get '1 2016' ?

Comment: Just completed that part, now seeing your answer. :)
Same thing i have done. Thanks anyways :)